# How to pass state variable data between two functions in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have two functions. My First.js function has two state variables that I want to send to Second.js . I have tried sending data using Stack Navigation route params but it keeps on saying
"undefined is not an object route.params.firstVariable"
How would I send data without using navigation?

Answer (score 0):

If the functions/components are mounted on different screens, you will have to pass them through the navigator. If they are on the same screen, you can pass them as props.

Share the code if you still have an issue

Comment: First.js is in a drawer navigation, and it uses stack navigation to navigate to Second.js. Second.js is not a drawer screen. Should I make Second.js a drawer screen and a stack screen>